# Restart programs on startup that were opened before shutdown

Tags: shutdown, startup, restart, startup-applications

I want some kind of tool or way, which gives me option to save open application before restart/shutdown and open them as soon as I login. This kind of feature is available in MacOS. 
I'm using Ubuntu 19.04 with Gnome Desktop Environment.

Comment: Sorry, Added the details!

Answer (score 6):

Problem is: there might be no good solution. Sorry to disappoint, but an honest answer depicting the situation is better than no answer.

In older versions of Gnome, you could enable the option to save a session. Then on logout, the open applications would be saved, and on next login, they would be launched again. This feature did not always work reliably, and was dropped.

Currently, to achieve the effect of being able to continue where you left, you may put your computer in *sleep* modus or in *hibernate* modus. Sleep means that everything is kept in memory. Then the computer goes in a very low power mode, just supplying power to the memory so its content is safeguarded. In *hibernate* modus, the contents of the RAM is written to SWAP memory on a swap partition. Then the system fully powers down. On startup, the system checks is a previous session is in SWAP, and restores that to memory.

Issue with *sleep* and especially *hibernate* is that it works not reliably in quite some hardware. This is especially a problem with *hibernate*, to the extent that hibernate is disabled by default on Ubuntu. However, you have more chance to have luck with *sleep* modus. If that works well on your hardware, it will work to your satisfaction. A laptop can be in sleep modus for quite some weeks before the battery runs out. If you are not using your computer for that long, it is obviously better to fully shut down on these occasions.

The reason it does not always works well is indeed what plagues linux in a more general sense: hardware manufacturers using proprietary systems for power management, or implementing it in a proprietary way such that linux developpers have no good documentation to support it.

Comment: I didn't know there were underlying problems regarding that. Thank you, that was very useful information. What I had in mind was some sort of dynamic startup application, which logs what applications were open before shutdown and start then after normal shutdown/reboot.

Comment: That was exactly how "sessions" worked, but alas, this has been abandonned in Gnome Shell. Please accept the answer if you consider it a correct answer to your question (though unfortunately not providing a fully satisfactory solution if sleep or hibernate would not work well, but that is how it is currently).

Comment: Yes, this is a great answer, most of us need to restart the computer just because the system needs to be changed.

Answer (score 0):

Now some laptops are able to perform what is called as "Modern Standby", also called S0 Low power standby... this is an amazing power state similar to Apple's close/open lid standby states...

However, laptops must have compatible BIOS S0 state. You should have to check with your laptop model. Unfortunately I haven't seen until now any Motherboard Desktop having this feature.

I'd suggest you some readings:

- [How to enable S0ix states on Linux (Official guide from intel)](https://01.org/blogs/qwang59/2018/how-achieve-s0ix-states-linux)
- [Modern Standby from Windows (nice reading)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/design/device-experiences/modern-standby)
- [Modern Standby versus S3 (also good reading from Microsoft)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/design/device-experiences/modern-standby-vs-s3)
- [Arch Linux guide on S0ix and s2idle states for DELL XPS](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Dell_XPS_13_(9360)#Sleep_to_idle_(s2idle,_S0ix)), but this also works for other compatible laptops

Answer (score 0):

Here is an extension that could work for you.
It only works on Xorg.

https://github.com/Speedflyer689/reopen_windows-gnome_extension

Comment: Your answer is confusing. Does it work or not?

Comment: Yes, it works if you are using Xorg.

Answer (score -1):

Start typing “dconf editor” in the search box. When the “dconf Editor” item displays, click on the icon to start the tool.

In the “dconf Editor” window, click the right arrow next to “org” in the left pane to expand that branch of the tree.

Under “org”, click the right arrow next to “gnome.”

Under “gnome,” click “gnome-session.”.In the right pane, select the “auto-save-session” check box to turn on the option.

Close the “dconf Editor” by clicking the “X” button in the upper-left corner of the window.

sourse: [it's old but...](https://www.howtogeek.com/203952/how-to-automatically-remember-running-applications-from-your-last-session-in-ubuntu-14.04/)

Comment: This did not work for me. On reboot it doesn't open the previous programs.

Comment: put your programs into startup applications... https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/startup-applications.html.en

Comment: But that would start some specific programs at startup. I'm looking for a way to start whatever programs were open during shutdown/reboot to start at login.